# Google API font not supported in IE8

Tags: css, google-font-api

i used below code for font support using from ,

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald|Play|Numans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

if i use the above URL, the fonts supported in all the browser.

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'Oswald';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Oswald '), local('Oswald'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/oswald/v2/-g5pDUSRgvxvOl5u-a_WHw.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Numans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Numans'), local('Numans-Regular'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/numans/v2/H6jkjoZl4TIrPYyjhdoCcw.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Play';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Play'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/play/v2/-SXnV4mZjf4oh1IBw13WZw.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v5/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff') format('woff');
}
```

i copied and paste the above css code in my CSS for fonts support.in IE8 Alone the font not supported. is there any fix for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that it stops working when you copy the CSS is that Google sends back different CSS depending on the user agent that made the request.

[The CSS returned for IE is different](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/technical_considerations.html#Serving) to the CSS you've copied.

So, if you're using Google Web Fonts, then use it with `<link href..` as recommended.

---

If you want to host the font locally, read this: [How to host google web fonts on my own server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966740/how-to-host-google-web-fonts-on-my-own-server)