# Cusom font with CSS - ONLY works with Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts, mozilla

I am making a website for a friend of mine. He is very specific about the font on the page. 
I have downloaded a custom font from the Internet, but the weird thing; it's *only* working in Internet Explorer (what a suprise).

This is my code:

```
@font-face
{
font-family: eurostile;
src: url(../font/eurostile.ttf);
} 
@font-face
{
font-family: eurostile;
src: url(../font/eurostile.eot);
}
```

And this is how I am calling the font-family:

```
  p 
    {
        font-family: eurostile;
    }
```

etc... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face

Comment: just to be sure, are you able to install the TTF onto a computer successfully? Might help to make sure the file isn't corrupt in some way. Sometimes people use font converters to get different filetypes and I've had that mess up my files before.

Comment: The font was good! I did not test this, but it could be a very good explanation.
The problem was my cross-browser problem, I forgot to add different filetypes :) @StaceyGarrison

Comment: Actually the problem was that you had 2 `@font-face` rules with exactly the same specifity, so all browsers tried to use the bottom one. Justice's answer correctly shows one `@font-face` rule with multiple src properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to format it in a cross platform style. Look [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/).

The problem is that different browsers support different font styles.

[image]

Something like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontMN';
    src: url('/fonts/font_font-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('/fonts/font_font-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('/fonts/font_font-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('/fonts/font_font-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('/fonts/font_font-webfont.svg#fontMN') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Would work.

You will need to acquire the formats that are valid for the browsers you're looking to support, as seen above.

Comment: he has enough fonts loaded for xbrowser (ttf and eot) but I bet adding the "format" part will help this work

Answer (score 0):

Browser use different formats. IE uses the eot format, most use woff, but some use svg or ttf/otf.

Check this out:

http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax

You can create all these fonts by uploading a ttf/otf to fontsquirrel and using it's converter:

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: he's using a font that SHOULD work in browsers other than IE (ttf) so it can't just be the font format, assuming the .ttf file isn't corrupt.

Comment: The .tff file worked in IE, no other. 
After I converted the file into several other files it worked

Answer (score 0):

http://jasonlau.biz/home/css/embedding-custom-fonts-with-css

If you ever need to embed custom fonts in your website, this bit of CSS will accomplish the task. Follow the steps below to embed custom fonts in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tool to generate the `font-face` rule - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator.