# Can't get font-face to use my font on Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

So I followed several guides on how to install a new font using @font-face. I have added the birch.ttf file to /wp-content/themes/zenon-lite and added the following to my Style.css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Birch;
src: url('birch.ttf');}

font-family: Birch, Georgia, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

And for each font-family I have listed Birch as the first option, yet I never get it. Any ideas on why it isn't working?

**Edit: It's a stupid error. Replaced font files and it worked ...**

Comment: You only attachted birch.ttf? What browser are you using? IE for example doesn't support .ttf

Comment: Google Chrome, can you attach multiple versions to support all browsers? I thought most versions [support ttf](http://caniuse.com/ttf)?

Comment: Yes, most of them. If you wan't good browsersupport, include them all.

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute path.

**For instance,**

```
@font-face {
font-family: Birch;
src: url('http://www.*yourpath*.***/birch.ttf');}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Edited it to `src: url('http://www.xxx.com/wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/birch.ttf');`, still no luck :(

Comment: Serious? Are you sure it's not just Georgia you're seeing? ;)

Comment: Wtf, could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I think you need to delete your cache

Comment: that's Georgia ;) Inspect element on Google Chrome and remove Georgia from the font-family, now you'll the text change to Arial :D

Comment: On my iPhone I see the correct font, but that messes up my text. Going to delete my cache.

Comment: Its 'birch', i removed it and got georgia and then when I removed georgia, i got arial.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39885/discussion-between-t-thielemans-and-nathan-lee)

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the same font format, Can you look into this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Birch';
    src: url('fonts/birch.eot');
    src: url('fonts/birch.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/birch.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/birch.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/birch.svg#HelveticaNeue65Medium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You need to convert your fonts .http://www.freefontconverter.com/

`fonts` is a folder where i kept my all fonts :)

Comment: I added this and an .woff font, still same result :(

Comment: Font [path original](http://www.shanaraeshairdesign.com/wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/birch.ttf), font path using your code for [TTF](http://www.shanaraeshairdesign.com/wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/fonts/birch.ttf) and [WOFF](http://www.shanaraeshairdesign.com/wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/fonts/birch.woff)

Comment: @t.thielemans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face read this..and be sure the path is correct..Everything is Perfect

Comment: Are you using Wordpress???  @t.thielemans then u should be very clear where u are keeping the files

Comment: Yes I am using WordPress. Yes the paths are correct. As you can tell by visiting the links I provided, it'll automatically download the font. I'm using Chrome Version 30.xxx

Comment: Updated my question. On the iPhone I can see Birch, just not on Chrome yet, also cleared my cache, etc.

Comment: @t.thielemans `@font-face {
font-family: Birch;
src: url('http://www.shanaraeshairdesign.com/wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/birch.ttf') format('truetype');
/*src: url('fonts/birch.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/birch.ttf') format('truetype');*/
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
` this is your code, You  have not given path for woff font

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39889/discussion-between-t-thielemans-and-deekey)