# Can I just use FA's CSS and SVG file or do I need .EOT, .TTF, and .OFF?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

due to security reasons, I can't use the Font Awesome CDN nor can I transfer over any files other than the Font Awesome's .css and the .svg files. The other .eot, .ttf, and .off files included in the download get stripped out when I try to transfer between secure networks.

So, does anyone know if I can just use the .css and .svg file or do I need all the others?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differing font files are included for browser compatibility. As to whether or not you can use just SVG, that depends on which browsers you want to support.

Take a look at this related question for a detailed explanation [Why should we include ttf, eot, woff, svg,... in a font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face/#answer-11002874)