# CSS - Unable to use downloaded fonts

Tags: css, fonts

There are 2 particular fonts that are pre-installed. They render fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. So I included the fonts using `@font-face` so they would be downloaded.

CSS:

```
@font-face
{
  font-family:Elephant;
  src:url('/Styles/Fonts/elephant.ttf');

  font-family:Harrington;
  src:url('/Styles/Fonts/Harrington.ttf');
}

.title
{
  font-family:Elephant;
}
.title2
{
  font-family:Harrington;
}
```

They still don't work in Firefox. What do I need to do?

Comment: in firefox you need to have the full url ;)

Comment: could you plz give an example. Also how about other browsers.

Comment: @jycr753 no you don't?

Comment: Use http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax and convert the multiple font types with http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: hmmmm maybe.. but still he is missing the rest of font vaiants

Comment: go to fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator and download the package with all the required font type and files

Comment: Thank you everyone. @chris answer worked for me. guess what ..in IE too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you need to have a separate `@font-face` rule for each font that you import/download for use in CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Elephant";
  src: url("/Styles/Fonts/elephant.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Harrington";
  src: url("/Styles/Fonts/Harrington.ttf");
}
```

Comment: that will not work, since `.ttf` font family are for Safari, Android, iOS

Comment: @jycr753 See the link above. If that's not enough, here's a webpage from the Mozilla Developer Network where they use a `.ttf` in their example: [tiny little link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Comment: yeah but still, that will only work for new browsers.. why dont respond the OP pointing to the right way declaring all needed parameters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face

Comment: either way... is good fun mate, but im in class ;) so lets agree to disagree

Comment: @jycr753 I don't mean to repeatedly challenge you or anything, but you are (again) incorrect. TTF support in Firefox dates all the way back to version 3.5 and Chrome supported it for as long as it's been around. Only browser that has issues is IE in its older versions. Have fun in class.

Comment: Maybe, i will look at it later ;) is always good to learn :) plus is fun ... thanks mate i will @Chris

Answer (score 1):

your download font links should be like so:

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'elephant';
    src: url('/Styles/Fonts/elephant.eot?#') format('eot'), /* IE6–8 */
    url('/Styles/Fonts/elephant.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
    url('/Styles/Fonts/elephant.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Saf3—5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
}
```

you can use [Web Font Ganarator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to Convert your font to `Woff` and `eot` and `svg` format

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox, you should write this way:

```
@font-face {
font-family: ‘FONT’;
src: url(‘FONT.eot’);
src: url(‘FONT.eot?#iefix’) format(‘embedded-opentype’),
url(‘FONT.woff’) format(‘woff’),
url(‘FONT.ttf’) format(‘truetype’),
url(‘FONT.svg#FONT’) format(‘svg’);
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

While `FONT` is your font, Elephant or Harrington.