# what fonts are really essential from the bootstrap fonts folder

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When i use bootstrap for intranet web apps, i usually have it hosted on my on server..
so here's what i have

```
/css
/js
/fonts
```

under css, i've minified bootstrap.css, under js i've jquery.min.js and bootstrap.js.

Under /fonts i see

```
glyphicon-halflings-regular.eot
glyphicon-halflings-regular.svg
glyphicon-halflings-regular.ttf
glyphicon-halflings-regular.woff
```

Now i presume that only one or two of them is being actually used for the web app, so which ones should i actually keep in the folder without my web app failing on modern browsers ( ie 10, ffox 20, chrome 30)

thanks..

Comment: The different font files are there to supports different font formats in multiple browsers. They're all essentially the same character set, just in different formats that different browsers understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not need these fonts unless you are using glyphicons http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use

Bootstrap uses safe webfonts like

```
"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
```

or

```
Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif
```

by default. And they are supported by majority of browsers http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: I'm not talking about typography, i'm talking about glyphycons, if i use them which of the four i need to have icons rendered correctly.  I know in the end it'll fallback to serif or sans-serif.

Comment: You need all of them in order to support all browsers. See here for more information about types http://stackoverflow.com/a/11002874/1022726

Comment: thank you @yuyokk for the link and the answer :) i'll henceforth use them all to have the most compatible version of my web app.