# 404 Not Found Glyphicons Bootstrap Work Around

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, iis

Is it possible to get bootstrap glyphicons to work without adding this code to web.config?

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Unfortunately I am unable to add this at my workplace but would still like to use the pagination from bootstrap. Is there any other way around this? These are the errors I am receiving.[image]

Maybe somehow download the images directly and change the bootstrap css to find the correct ones? All I need is the pagination ones at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: this question might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133497/bootstrap-about-fonts-files-roles-and-usages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use bootstrap pagination even if glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 or glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff cant be found.

Bootstrap is coming with glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf by default. The browser will use the first compatible font file that it will found and ttf is well supported.

For more information: [Why should we include ttf, eot, woff, svg,... in a font-face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face)

Maybe something is wrong in your html.

Answer (score 3):

Try going to the file's address and fix it from there. If it's not there too then just use a CDN: [Bootstrap CDN | MaxCDN](http://bootstrapcdn.com)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to:

- Use Bootstrap hosted on a CDN
- Build or modify bootstrap and remove the woff fonts
- A combination of the two, modify your own Bootstrap to use woff files from a CDN
- Rewrite the glyphicon part of Bootstrap to use images (probably the worst idea, but it would work).