# How to use fontawesome in Chrome Extension?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, font-awesome

I am developing a Google Chrome Extension that is displayed on a specific website. And I want to use Fontawesome in my chrome extension.
When I try to load fonts, the error `GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED` occured.

In the stylesheet, webfonts are included with `@font-face` like this.

```
src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/Fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
```

I also tried to embed my extension id directly, though it doesn't work.

My manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["Fonts/*.*", "*.ttf", "*.eot", "*.svg", "*.woff", "*.woff2"],
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you created it like a npm project? do you have a package.json file?

Comment: @NuwanKarunarathna are you kidding? He's making a Chrome extension, not a Javascript stand-alone project...

Comment: @Noctumsempra So what? Do you think a Chrome Extension cannot have a package.json file or it cannot be a stand-alone javascript project?  How many chrome extensions have you developed?

Answer (score 16):

I'd like to add upon [@Thomas Kekeisen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54957601/3002584) with an updated answer for version 5 (current version is 5.13.0) of FontAwesome.
Also, I'd like to keep things as minimal as possible, and so:

1. I will only refer to `woff2`, [since there's no reason to use another format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002874/3002584).
2. I will only refer to FontAwesome's `regular` style (this is one of their [5 styles](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use)).

Therefore, if you're using a format other than `woff2`, or a style other than `regular`, just apply the following to it in the same way.

---

So, in order to use FontAwesome in Chrome extensions, do as follows:

1. [Download FontAwesome .zip file](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/fontawesome-free-5.13.0-web.zip) (that's a direct download link, you can visit the download page [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself)).
2. Extract the .zip, and only take what's needed, which in our example are:

   (a) `css/fontawesome.min.css`
   (b) `css/regular.min.css`
   (c) `webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2`

   *Note: If you're using `css/all.min.js`, it replaces both (a) and (b).*
3. *Optional, and would make our life easier*:

   Under your Chrome extension root folder, create the folders `css` and `webfonts` to mimic FontAwesome structure, and move the files listed above into these folders.
   Your folder structure should look as follows:

   ```
   your-extension
    |- css
      |- fontawesome.min.css
      |- regular.min.css
    |- webfonts
      |- fa-regular-400.woff2
   ```
4. Inside `css/regular.min.css`, override (yes, just override it) `@font-face` media style with the following:

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 400;
     font-display:block;
     src: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2");
   }
   ```

   *Note: Let me remind again that I refer to the `regular` style as an example, so if you're using another style, make sure the `@font-face.src` property has the correct value*.
5. Update your `manifest.json` as follows:

   ```
   {
     ...
     "content_scripts": [{
        ...
        "css": [
           "css/fontawesome.min.css",
           "css/regular.min.css",
        ]
        ...
     }],
     ...
     "web_accessible_resources": [
        ...
       "css/fontawesome.min.css",
       "css/regular.min.css",
       "webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2", // or: "webfonts/*" 
     ]
   }
   ```

   *Note: it's needed to add the `.css` paths into both `"content_scripts"` and `"web_accessible_resources"`*.

Comment: Thank you for a very useful and detailed post. wanted to add that based on my testing so far, the .css files are not required in the web_accessible_resources section of the manifest though.

Comment: In my case I tried to set up the fontAwesome for popup so I only downloaded all.min.css and all .woff2 files (atm of typing - fontawesome-5.15.2 - 3 files in webfonts folder) I put them into myFolder/css/all.min.css and myFolder/webfonts/ 3 .woff2 files
Then in my popup I linked the location of all.min.css file:
`<link href="/myFolder/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
You don't need to put anything in manifest.json if you only want to use it in popup. Another explanation: [docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself#using-web-fonts)

Comment: @GoodOldGuy, please put your comment as an answer. Both your answers cover all bases!

Answer (score 10):

This is how I managed to get a local (offline) instance of fontawesome (4.7) in my chrome extension:

1) Download font files (`FontAwesome.otf`, `fontawesome-webfont.eot`, `fontawesome-webfont.svg`, `fontawesome-webfont.ttf`, `fontawesome-webfont.woff`, `fontawesome-webfont.woff2`) to `fonts/`

2) Download `font-awesome.min.css` to `css/` and replace all urls in this file `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/[...]`.

3) Update your `manifest.json` like this:

```
{
    ...
    "content_scripts":          [
        {
           ...
            "css":        [
                "css/font-awesome.min.css",
                ...
            ]
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        ...
        "fonts/FontAwesome.otf",
        "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot",
        "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg",
        "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf",
        "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff",
        "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2",
    ]
}
```

This makes fontawesome available offline (you don't need any fontawesome-js for this).

Comment: I found the download link for the fa fonts here: https://devdreamz.com/question/248929-how-to-use-fontawesome-in-chrome-extension or directly: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use Font Awesome a Chrome Extension's content script (not the popup.html), you can do the following:

Download `https://use.fontawesome.com/840a321d95.js`, rename it to `fontawesome.js` and include it in your extension's directory as described in @wesdotcool's answer.

Then add the following to `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": ["fontawesome.js"]
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: This didn't work when extension was loaded on twitter.com. The error I am seeing in console `Refused to load the font 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com data: https://ton.twitter.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com 'self'".\`

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me. It may be because all the answers are outdated since they refer to older versions of Font Awesome.
I solved it when I found [what Font Awesome 6 suggests on their official website](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts).

### In short:

- [Download the Font Awesome zip File **for the web**](https://fontawesome.com/download)
- Extract everything in your project folder
- Copy the path to get at `css/all.css`, `css` is a folder inside the one you just extracted
- Paste the following in the head of your HTML:

```
<link href="/your-path-to-fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Note: **Make sure to insert the correct path.**

#### Some great tutorials to get the path of a file:

- [Get the full path of a file on **Windows**](https://www.howtogeek.com/670447/how-to-copy-the-full-path-of-a-file-on-windows-10/)
- [Get the full path of a file on **Linux**](https://www.howtouselinux.com/post/linux-command-get-file-path#:%7E:text=The%20best%20Linux%20command%20to,will%20be%20the%20file%20path.)
- [Get the full path on of a file **macOS**](https://setapp.com/how-to/how-to-find-the-path-of-a-file-in-mac)

Comment: Should be the top comment, cheers @jock

Answer (score 2):

The simplest, yet terrible, way is to download Fontawesome and include it directly

```
curl -o fontawesome.js "https://use.fontawesome.com/840a321d95.js"
```

and then add it where you need it

```
<script src="fontawesome.js"></script>
```

Comment: This also works in the chrome extension's `manifest.json` for content scripts.

Comment: This didn't work when extension was loaded on twitter.com. The error I am seeing in console `Refused to load the font 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com data: https://ton.twitter.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com 'self'".\`

Comment: I think is not working anymore, can somebody update?

Answer (score 1):

I successfully was able to use Font Awesome using Sass in my chrome extension.

Steps to integrate `FontAwesome 5.11.x` in your chrome extension using sass:

1. Go to [Font Awesome Download page](https://fontawesome.com/download) to download a **local copy** of the web-specific files.
2. Copy the `SCSS` folder into your styles folder.
3. Copy the entire `webfonts` folder into assets folder.
4. Open the font awesome `scss/variables.scss` and edit the `$fa-font-path` variable to point to where you placed the webfonts folder.

You'll need to use `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/` to find the path of the extension folder.

For me the path to font files were - `extension/chrome/assets/font-awesome`,
so I changed `$fa-font-path` to `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/font-awesome`.

5. Import Font Awesome by adding `@import "scss/fontawesome.scss"` in your main SCSS file. Also, import one or more styles `@import "scss/solid.scss"` in your main SCSS file. If you're using regular font, then import `regular.scss`.

Execute your web extension and you should be able to use font awesome icons.

Answer (score 0):

My use case is the following, I am adding icons to one page, not to the popup, to the page where I am generating divs, and buttons, and text, and stuff.

I finally did it by just appending a <script element containing the fontawesome.js to the page where my extension was adding the icons.

```
if(!document.getElementById("fontawesome_styling_script")){
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.id = "fontawesome_styling_script"
        script.src = "https://kit.fontawesome.com/name_of_file.js";
        script.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script);
    }
```

Get the .js file by creating a kit in the fontawesome webpage.

I tried everything before this and it just worked, I have only tested it with one page, so it might not work for other cases, but I'll leave it here in case it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your manifest: `"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://kit.fontawesome.com/[FILE_NAME].js; object-src 'self'"`

Refresh your extension.

**Edit:** This method doesn't seem to work for Manifest V3

Comment: Would be better if you were to explain why this will resolve the problem.