# Why it's important to link multiple font formats in icon fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I want to use [Material Icons](https://material.io/icons/) for all of my website projects. When i download the [source code of Material Icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/material-icons.css), I can see in CSS file, there are multiple font formats includes such as WOFF, WOFF2, SVG, TTF, EOT.
I remove all excluding TTF. And the icon fonts are working fine. I why other font families are reured.

Comment: Because not all browsers (browser versions) support TTF or all of the other formats.

Comment: Just search on google : `font-face CSS` ... When you read the basics about the use of custom fonts you understand why and which formats you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should we include ttf, eot, woff, svg,... in a font-face](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face)

Comment: i already read this [page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp) and found TTF works in most of the browsers.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=ttf is the much better resource for browser compatibility.

Comment: The sad truth is that while most other formats are supersets of TTF (that is, they're based on TTF, but they have more features), programs that can convert a TTF font into, e.g. into a WOFF2 font, cannot add features that aren't there in the first place, so you basically end up with the same functionality. Maybe in the future, when there are native WOFF2 font editors, will this format offer real benefits over plain TTF.

Comment: You kept the wrong one. **Keep WOFF**, everything else is irrelevant for modern browsers (except for WOFF2 which has better compression and subsetting). @str that's an answer from 2012, which in terms of webfonts is about as useful as HTML3.2 advice is today - we've literally abandoned at least two font formats since then (eot and svg fonts are no longer a thing). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration/36110385#36110385 for a modern explanation of the format stack needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are eot, ttf, and svg still necessary in the font-face declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration)