# How to use google webfonts in a locked-down intranet?

Tags: css, google-font-api

Working on a client project - reskinning their intranet. The way their security is set up, all external media is denied, including any Google Fonts. The tricky part is they're requiring us to restyle with a Google Font.

Prompting users to install the font themselves is, of course, unacceptable. Is there a way I can download a Google Font file and put it locally on the website?

---

**UPDATE**: After a bit of legwork, I found that you can download and use the compressed version of a google font to keep your site relatively optimized. Go to the import URL:

`http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700,300italic`

In the `src` attribute (the themes.googleusercontent.com URL) download the `.woff` file it links to, rename it as you please, upload it to your website's media directory, then point to that local file instead of Google's URL.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966740/what-is-the-correct-way-of-hosting-google-web-fonts-on-my-own-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download them from Google and host them on your own server

[image: The download button]

Use the download button in the upper right corner at Google Fonts to download your collection

---

See https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq#Download_Fonts

Comment: Not brilliant. What if the device they are using on the network does not support true type fonts?

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike already mentioned in a comment, there is [localfont.com](http://localfont.com/) which helps you download all font variants and generates cross-browser CSS for implementation. What you get from Google Fonts itself is ONLY TTF and therefore will not work on all Browsers. What you can manually download by accessing the Google CSS file actually depends on which Browser you use. localfont.com provides TTF, WOFF, WOFF2, EOT and SVG for all fonts available on Google Fonts.