# How to use Google Web Font in my web-application without any external links?

Tags: css, google-font-api, web-deployment-project

I need to use some google fonts on an my web-application. The clients may or may not have internet connection.

Is there any legal way to use it legally?

like,

https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans:400,300italic,300
to
https://www.example.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans:400,300italic,300

Thanks in advance...

Comment: it is only available for local network only. There is no internet in network.

Comment: in short want to use google font offline in LAN.

Comment: answer is  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966740/how-to-host-google-web-fonts-on-my-own-server