# Is it possible to specify a font version in the google fonts api?

Tags: google-font-api

A Google font we use (Pacifico) recently had a rather radical redesign to the capital 'L'. As we use this for our product with a name begging with 'L' this caused a rather radical change in the look to our product.

Digging into it, I noticed that the url for the fonts had changed from

```
fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v7/Q_Z9mv4hySLTMoMjnk_rCXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff2
```

to

```
fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v8/Q_Z9mv4hySLTMoMjnk_rCXYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff2
```

but that the previous v7 urls still worked. So, for now, I have added hardcoded font references to that version.

Is it possible, though, to instead link to a particular version of a font?

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

So, somehow specify a version in the above link?

I have tried various guesses, such as:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&version=7
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico&version=v7
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico:v7
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended way to stick with a particular version is to self-host it.

Google does not and will not have a versioning option.
The API `v7` hack you're using is officially not recommended, and may break.

A Google Fonts employee “davelab6” has been responding to several questions like yours on the Google Fonts github. [This question](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/1316) is much like yours and has a brief answer from him. It also links to [several](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/1307) [other](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/1308) [issues](https://github.com/JulietaUla/Montserrat/issues/60#issuecomment-343633544) with *spirited* discussion about a similar change.
The upshot is that Google has considered offering a versioning feature and rejected it for several reasons. They say the vast majority of users will be fine with the latest version of a font, and the rest can self-host the version they like.

As for *how* to self-host, I'm out of my depth, but there's [a question about it here with several answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966740/how-to-host-google-web-fonts-on-my-own-server).