# Angular 4 Project doesn't work offline

Tags: angular, web, responsive-design, e-commerce, frontend

I'm working on E-commerce Project using Angular 4,Bootstrap,font-awesomes and i'm also using .scss file and angular-cli, and I've built slider on my own.
I've installed all libraries,images and any file offline.

The problem here if i'm offline the project work but as if there is no style and the slider doesn't work, and if i'm online it works will.

Online => [The slider is work and there is no problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1WkG.png)

offline => [Slideer is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOFFv.png)
and it gave me these messages in the console

```
Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSq-j2U0lmluP9RWlSytm3ho.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSpX5f-9o1vgP2EXwfjgl7AY.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNShWV49_lSm1NYrwo-zkhivY.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSqaRobkAwv3vxw3jMhVENGA.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSv8zf_FOSsgRmwsS7Aa9k2w.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSj0LW-43aMEzIO6XUTLjad8.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSugdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:4200/glyphicons-halflings-regular.448c34a56d699c29117a.woff2
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:4200/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff
localhost/:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:4200/fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf
core.es5.js:2925 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

I need a solution so that, i can run the project offline and works well like online

Comment: Have a look at [This](https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers) Post

Comment: try hosting your fonts on your own server

Comment: @Paul how i can do this ?

Comment: @AhmedE.Eldeeb https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966740/how-to-host-google-web-fonts-on-my-own-server

Comment: thanks @Paul that's helped me can you put your answer  in a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the slider itself, you are using jquery to make it work and that cause some problem try to use angular version of the slider like Slick
[https://github.com/devmark/ngx-slick](https://github.com/devmark/ngx-slickhttp://)